# How do you quit the Vi editor with single keypress?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vi

Because honestly

```
:wq!
```

is just too much to type.

Please note that the question is about original Vi (say Vi which comes with FreeBSD) not Vim.

Comment: Is closing the editor with a single keypress not a bit...uhm...insecure?

Comment: Oh what if you select "Enter" to be that "one key", then all the code is on one row :/ *sarcasm*

Comment: Filip's comment is meant to be funny, but kinda doesn't work... you can use Vi very effectively without ever using "Enter" in Normal, Visual, Operator-pending, or Insert modes.  Only Command mode *requires* "Enter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on solaris' old version of vi:

```
Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0

$ vi -c "map g ZZ" test
```

**edit**: Also, this seems to work:

```
$ vi -c 'map g :q!^M' test
```

Where ^M is actually, ^V (ctl-v) then ^M (ctl-m)

Comment: Yeah, it works, nice! Actually I already regret that I didn't state which version I want (i.e. with saving or without), so is there any way to put Enter character in mapped sequence? It would be possible to "map g :q!<Enter>" to quit without saving.

Comment: it seems like this works too:

$ vi -c 'map g :q!^M' test

Where ^M is actually, ^V then ^M

Answer (score 20):

Hold down the shift key and bang on Z twice.

`ZZ` is (mostly) equivalent to `:wq!`.

If you really want a single-keystroke solution, FreeBSD comes with the source so, in a pinch, you could modify that and re-compile. It's a bit of an overkill but it'll solve your problem.

Comment: And for dolzenko's edification, ZQ is (mostly) equivalent to :q!  I definitely use them a lot more than :wq/:q.

Answer (score 3):

What about "ZZ"? It has slightly different semantics to ":wq!", but is also slightly shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Map your favourite key to the :wq! command.

e.g. put this in your .vimrc:

```
map <F8> :wq!<CR>
```

Et voilá.

Edit:
*Sorry, vim only, missed that.*

Answer (score 1):

Does `:x` work on Vi? Although for your case I guess it might be `:x!`

Comment: you don't need the last !, you just need to press ESC, type :wq and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gvim you can close it with `ALT+F4`.  Two keys, but one keypress.

If you're using vi in its own xterm, `ALT+F4` should close the xterm, killing vi as well.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the tried and true?

```
:x
```

It's not one key press, but it's much less than :wq! which is what your question appears to truly seek.

Or is this a ViM only feature? My apologies if so.