# How to exit from PostgreSQL command line utility: psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

What command or short key can I use to exit the PostgreSQL command line utility `psql`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm not shocked by the question, but the number of upvotes :) Compare e.g. to [How do you quit the Vi editor with single keypress?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/468939/)

Comment: Sometimes we need quick and straight forward answer than searching it in the manual to focus on the real problem.In such cases these short questions are really helpful.

Comment: The real question is not _"are people capable of reading a manual"_, but _"should enterprise software respond to standard exit sequences"_ like, I don't know, "exit"? Having to read the manual to quit seems seriously counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Kheldar Indeed, it's just bad user interface design (coupled with arrogance). People are insecure about weird things.

Comment: more importantly, this post is now the first hit when i google "exit psql"

Comment: Excellent example of horrible usability (of a otherwise great product)! This is why development is so frustrating sometimes...

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried exit, quit, bye.. then \quit \exit. Eventually \h for help, but \? was what I should have used...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think `\?` is the sensible answer to this lazy question and similar ones. Teach a man to fish etc ... And that's the one you deleted.

Comment: Other non-lazy answers for lazy questions: - "Can I have your number?"  - "Yes, sure, look it up in a phone book." ;)  I know, better to give a fishing rod than a fish. But I think it's not always the case - not when someone needs a fish very quickly or/and is a vegan and needs fish only once for uncle Tom that is visiting once a year. Best answer probably would be to give both. So after reading one would know how to quit psql and would know how to check how to quit (or look up other commands) if he/she miracelously doesn't know that already (didn't read info on the screen?).

Comment: I usually quit psql in frustration because I can't figure out how to make it DO anything. The reason for this was because I didn't realize you must add a ; to the end of SQL statements in psql, or they are considered incomplete and don't get executed.

Comment: @NessBird Pretty much any SQL *shell* requires semi-colons at the end of statements, even for MSSQL and other variants that don't normally require them in general.

Comment: spent 2 minutes to look for "exit" command in documentation.

spent 10 seconds to google an answer on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2677, accepted):

Type `\q` and then press `ENTER` to quit `psql`.

**UPDATE: 19-OCT-2018**

As of *PostgreSQL 11*, the keywords "`quit`" and "`exit`" in the PostgreSQL command-line interface have been included to help make it easier to leave the command-line tool.

Comment: This won't work if you are in single user backend mode (`--single`). Instead use [Kaarel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12106607/623735) (`Ctrl-D`). In addition to always working in pgsql it'll work in most your other unix shells (python, mysql, etc). If you always do things the "standard" way in 'nix your brain will be less cluttered with trivia.

Comment: I actually typed that .. but it seems that on my machine it started to give me some output only after actually connecting to a database.

Comment: Type \? for help if just "help" doesn't help. This is a gleaming example of how not to create human computer interaction. Who thought of this great idea of \? for help and \q to quit?

Comment: Ctrl-d also help

Comment: As of [PostgreSQL 11 you can now type "quit" or "exit"](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1894/).

Comment: @aorth Yes, they announced it a few months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50513432/5070879

Comment: `quit` may be deprecated and does not function. Just tried and error received `bash: quit: command not found`; `exit` cmd seems to work however

Comment: @hnhl that are clearly commands for the bash shell, not postgresql shell.

Answer (score 810):

My usual key sequence is:

```
quit()
quit
exit()
exit
q
q()
!q
^C
help
Alt + Tab
google.com
Quit PSQL
\q
```

I think veterans of the psql command line usually shorten that to just:

```
\q
```

Comment: I tried ctrl-z, myself.  It got the job done, more or less, but I wasn't entirely satisfied.  :(

Comment: cntrl+D to exit from any where

Comment: @mjwach ctrl+z just suspends the process to the background, almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: postgres=# /q
postgres-# \q

Comment: Had a laugh with your answer. Brainsmashed due to all different tools we use.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your humor.  Mine was google.com then click the link for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463318/how-to-exit-from-postgresql-command-line-utility-psql?rq=1

Comment: I wish all questions on SO could have one answer like this one.

Comment: I think you missed :q

Comment: /q definitely doesn't work.

Comment: You missed an 'Alt+Tab' after 'Quit PSQL' :P

Answer (score 320):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is what I usually use to exit psql console.

Comment: Yep. This also works in bash, sh, ssh, zsh, irb, pry, python, sudo su, node, and more. It is _the_ standard way to exit a shell of any kind.

Comment: Not just a shell.  Any reasonably sane program which reads from stdin and interprets the empty string as EOF will accept ^D.

Comment: This does not work for me, probably because I use the Dvorak keyboard layout on OSX.  Neither cmd-D nor cmd-E (where D is on Qwerty) works.

Comment: @NessBird Ctrl is not the same as Cmd. Try Control-D instead of Command-D.

Comment: @Kevin you don't have to interpret the empty string as EOF.. by default sending ctrl+D will make you actually receive EOF from fgetc() (int=-1), and it will close the stdin file stream: any subsequent call to f*read*() will return error and feof(stdin) will return 1. So it's even easier to recognize it :)

Answer (score 36):

Use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - this sends the `TSTP` signal (`TSTP` is short for “terminal stop”)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - this sends the `QUIT` signal

For curiosity:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - this sends the `EOF` character. `EOF` stands for "end of file". In this concrete case it exits from the psql subprogram, as the shell is waiting for user input. This should not be 'the way to go' as it is not working if:
- any other character is entered before - try entering some white spaces and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it's not going to exit psql.
- if the user input is not required at all

Comment: There is no need to "try" anything. The proper command to cleanly exit `psql` is [well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and is `\q`

Comment: As *@hobs* clearly states about `\q`: "This won't work if you are in single user backend mode (--single). Instead use Kaarel's answer (`CtrlD`)". IMHO using `CtrlD` is not the way to go either, and I explained why above and offered an alternative.

Comment: Thank you! `Ctrl+Z` was the only command that worked for me - I was connected to a database via tunnel which lost the connection - neither `\q` nor `Ctrl+D` worked, but I could `Ctrl+Z` and then kill the suspended process

Comment: You may consider substituting the word 'try' with 'use' at the top of this answer. It brings in a feeling of 'not sure', yet this is a straight-forward and working answer to the question.

Answer (score 26):

## `quit` or `exit` or `\q`

Based on [PostgreSQL 11 Beta 1 Released!](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1855/):

> ## User Experience Enhancements
>
> Another feature that fell into this category was the inability to intuitively quit from the PostgreSQL command-line (psql). There has been numerous recorded complaints of users trying to quit with the **quit** and **exit** commands, only to learn that the command to do so was **\q.**
>
> We have heard your frustrations and have now added the ability to quit the command-line using the keywords **quit** and **exit** and hope that quitting a PostgreSQL session is now as enjoyable as using PostgreSQL.

Comment: bad habits, bad habits everywhere

Comment: @randomware Could you elaborate?

Comment: yes, i mean backslash was satisfactory and consistent with the other internal semicolonless pgsql commands, and one would do `\?` or `\h` to continue learning 'everything else' imho

Comment: "There has been numerous recorded complaints" -> "backslash was satisfactory"? Heh.

Answer (score 10):

I learned that I could include \q in a batch .sql file, so I could have psql quit earlier from an \i operation.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, `\q`, `exit` and `CTRL + D` didn't work for me to exit from the **psql** program.

```
Ctrl + Shift + D
```

This worked for me.

My Ubuntu version is **19.04**.