# How do I cancel a bad command in Postgres (from terminal)?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I wrote a bad command( I made a mistake in the function and want to exit it without completing the function) while trying to write a function, and I want to exit it,but the command prompt of Terminal wont let me.

I tried this :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45646/how-do-i-exit-or-cancel-a-bad-bash-command

also this

stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly

But none of the solutions given work, I am in this situation now (I was trying to write a pgplsql function and I wanted to end it, but I don't know how)

```
message=# create function add_message(_queue_id integer, _sender_id integer, _receiver_id integer, _payload text)
message-# returns integer as $$
message$# declare
message$# result integer;
message$# begin
message$# ;
message$# ;
message$# ;
message$# ;
message$# sdsd
message$# end
message$# ;
message$# return result;
message$# end
message$# <aa
message$# -ls
message$# ls
message$# abort
message$# v
message$#
```

**I tried :**

```
ctrl + /
crtl+D
ctrl+Z
ctrl+C
esc key
exit 0
:q
```

Note: I am using a osx keyboard with swiss-german layout.

Comment: "a bad command"? To what?  Are you using some pgplsql interactive client or something?

Comment: I started writing a plsql function and made a mistake,I want to exit it without completing it, so I would like to know in general how to exit a command without completing it.

Comment: And what program are you using to write this function?

Comment: I am using the Terminal, but running postgresql

Comment: And `postgresql` is an interactive client program?

Comment: yes postgres is a client program

Comment: It's got nothing to do with Terminal then and everything to do with this particular program and how it behaves.  Please edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463318/how-to-exit-from-postgresql-command-line-utility-psql#9463370

Answer (score 18):

I realize this is an old post, but this was my question too and took some time to eventually find the answer. By terminal, I believe op meant psql command line.

`\r` or `\reset` was what I was looking for.
Resets (clears) the query buffer.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html

Answer (score -1):

From postgresql try `\q`. See [exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463318/how-to-exit-from-postgresql-command-line-utility-psql#9463370) for more.
Or, for more drastic cases:
From another terminal window do

```
ps
```

it will give a list like

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
57839 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
57838 ttys001    0:00.05 -bash
57840 ttys002    0:00.17 -bash
```

divine which is the offending process and kill it

```
kill 57839
```

A new terminal should come up with a later number. See [Processes and Daemons](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/basics-processes.html) for more.

Comment: if i do \q wont it exit psql totally?

Comment: @LoveMeow Are you being serious?

Comment: @robert is there something else like ctrl-d that just exits the current command?

Comment: Programs can take control of all characters so it really depends on what postgresql does. So you can learn more about postgresql or just start over (the kill or even a reboot will do this.) It all depends on where you want to devote your learning curve. You could also just try typing a bunch of ')' and '}' to see if that will finish what you started to enter.

Answer (score -1):

```
nrssagg'> 
nrssagg'> 
nrssagg'> Select * from feed;
nrssagg'> ;
nrssagg'> \r
nrssagg'> \reset 
nrssagg'> ;
nrssagg'> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
nrssagg'> \d+
nrssagg'> \q
Use control-D to quit.
```

`Ctrl + d` on Linux.

PostgreSQL: 16.1 (Ubuntu 16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1)

Comment: What does this add to Douglas Lee's 2019 answer?

Comment: @greybeard
Douglas's answer uses the `\r` or `\reset` but that did not work for me on my Linux OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The client tells you exactly what is wrong here: `nrssagg'>`. Note the `'` character after database name. You need to first close the string, because you're in a multiline string mode at this point. That's why the `\r` doesn't work. If you close the string by using the suggested character like so: `'\r` it will work.